# Determine if rolling mean is increasing or decreasing using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a quick way, using pandas, to determine if a rolling mean over a series is increasing or decreasing?

Right now I do this to plot a rolling mean on my plots:

```
grouped.get_group(key)['COUNT'].rolling(window=30, center=False).mean()
```

This gives me a 30 day average. I'd like to compare the last thirty days to the thirty day block before for that (current day - 60 through current day - 31). Then I could determine if the trend is increasing or decreasing.

How can I do this comparison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the shift function to shift the Series and then compare, like so

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame ({'a':np.random.rand(100)})
df = df.assign (b = df.a.shift(30))
df.assign (c = df.a>df.b)


a   b   c
0   0.812733    NaN False
1   0.458400    NaN False
2   0.248011    NaN False
3   0.143784    NaN False
4   0.821032    NaN False
... ... ... ...
95  0.214292    0.458125    False
96  0.770356    0.208277    True
97  0.373172    0.373885    False
98  0.179586    0.860838    False
99  0.657406    0.297257    True
```